# What is a 'Timed Boost Landing' and how to perform it?

Tags: onrush

Strangely, none of the classes in *Onrush* seem to have much in the way of documentation explaining their abilities.  The *Vortex* buggy has a skill that says:

> Touchdown: Timed boost landings are more effective

How do I make use of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perform a timed landing when, after a jump, the boost is activated in the right moment when the wheels touch the ground.
If done with the right timing you get a boost with every vehicle, and Vortex buggy has the better boost of this kind as explained in your quote.